# How do i can make a muti-line-textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to build up a note app since every note entity of my `noteapp` has a property by the name of the body that it is a String. my issue is that in my AddOrUpdateScreen how can make a `textfield` that gets a size based on its content if I add more text it should get more space. I searched in *stackOverFlow* for other similar questions that they recommended setting `maxLines: null` and `expands: true` I have done them but none of them was the best fit for the app.

This is my actual code for `AddOrUpdateScreen`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:note_app_last_one/config/routes/my_router.dart';
import 'package:note_app_last_one/features/label/domain/entity/labelx.dart';
import 'package:note_app_last_one/features/note/domain/entities/notex.dart';
import 'package:note_app_last_one/features/note/presetation/riverpod/providers.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

class AddOrUpdateNotePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Notex note;
  final Labelx? label;

  const AddOrUpdateNotePage({super.key, this.label, required this.note});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _AddOrUpdateNotePageState();
}

class _AddOrUpdateNotePageState extends ConsumerState<AddOrUpdateNotePage> {
  late TextEditingController desCTL;

  late String body;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    desCTL = TextEditingController(text: widget.note.body ?? '');
    body = desCTL.text;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    desCTL.dispose();
    body = '';
    super.dispose();
  }

  Notex addNote() {
    if (widget.label != null) {
      widget.note.labels.add(widget.label!);
    }
    widget.note.body = body;

    Notex notex = ref.read(noteCRUDProvider).addOrUpdateNotex(widget.note);
    return notex;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        shadowColor: null,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            addNote();
            GoRouter.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: TextField(
              expands: true,
              maxLines: null,
              onChanged: (newDes) {
                setState(() {
                  body = newDes;
                });
              },
              controller: desCTL,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'description',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Wrap(
            children: [
              for (final label in widget.note.labels)
                Chip(label: Text(label.name ?? ''))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      persistentFooterAlignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.library_add_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              final note = addNote();
              context.push('/${AppRoutes.addLabelsToNote}', extra: note);
            }),
        const Spacer(),
        Text(timeago.format(widget.note.updatedTime)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But the issue is that when I run it these errors happen:

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type _OverflowBarParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a OverflowBar widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  SizedBox.shrink ← Expanded ← Spacer ← OverflowBar ← Align ← Padding ← Container ← IntrinsicHeight ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
framework.dart:6230
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
framework.dart:6247
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
framework.dart:6270
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6154
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6433
...     Normal element mounting (13 frames)
#17     Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:4182
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6569  74     Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:4182
#75     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6569
#76     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6581
...     Normal element mounting (332 frames)
#408    Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:4182
#409    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6569
#410    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3707
#411    Element.updateChildren
framework.dart:3894
#412    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6594
#413    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3685
#414    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5322
#415    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5462
#416    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:5016
#417    StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5485
#418    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3685
#419    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5322
#420    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:5016
#421    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5628
#422    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3685
#423    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5322
#424    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:5016
#425    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5628
#426    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
inherited_noti
```

Also These errors at the end happened and were repeated at least then time:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

The relevant error-causing widget was

TextField

add_or_update_note_page.dart:70

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

RenderBox was not laid out: \_RenderDecoration#f161d relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':

box.dart:1

Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was

TextField

add_or_update_note_page.dart:70

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are encountering are related to the use of the `TextField` widget inside a `SizedBox` with `expands: true` and `maxLines: null`. These properties are causing conflicts in the layout calculations.

To create a text field that grows based on its content, you can use a different approach using the `Expanded` widget within a `Column`.

Replace `body` with this:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: null,
        controller: desCTL,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'description',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Wrap(
      children: [
        for (final label in widget.note.labels)
          Chip(label: Text(label.name ?? ''))
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Isn't `Flexible Widget` be better choice than `Expanded` here?

Comment: The Expanded widget in flutter is shorthand of Flexible with the default fit of FlexFit.tight. If FlexFit need to be change Flexible is a better option.

Comment: Thanks man it was helpful but using persistentFooterButtons cause exceptions but how i can get my desired UI.

Comment: And how i can make it more efficient i mean what if the textfield get as much smaller space it can and also the Wrap widget be under the texfield and they get just one scroll controller for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may work

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        shadowColor: null,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            // addNote();
            // GoRouter.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            // expands: true,
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: (newDes) {
              setState(() {
                body = newDes;
              });
            },
            controller: desCTL,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'description',
            ),
          ),
          /*     Wrap(
            children: [
              for (final label in widget.note.labels)
                Chip(label: Text(label.name ?? ''))
            ],
          ), */
        ],
      ),
      persistentFooterAlignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.library_add_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              /*  final note = addNote();
              context.push('/${AppRoutes.addLabelsToNote}', extra: note); */
            }),
        // const Spacer(),
        Text("timeago.format(widget.note.updatedTime)"),
      ],
    );
```

****Note: this is mainly for that multiline text field , so I have commented down few codes... do have a look and alter it accordingly

Update***

The same code works properly for me.
here is a snap of it

[image: Referal Image]

Comment: but i still get the same exceptions

Comment: and persistentFooterButtons made exceptions i don't know why????? it is really weird!!

Comment: I have attached the screenshot where the same code works properly

Comment: ok u did right but i want to something like this i have a note entity that related to some labels when i add label to the note it should appear under the textfield but the textfield get all of space and it appear at the bottom of the screen and also the persistentFooterButtons made for my screen above exceptions!@

Comment: the textfield get all of space not based on its content other issue is that how i can make scrolling more efficient i mean if i add more text at least 20 line the textfield get the scrollbar but the labels is at bottom of the screen how i can make them to scroll together not apart

Comment: for me if i add the persistentFooterButtons the exceptions thrown but if i remove the persistentFooterButtons the exceptions note appear anymore

Comment: so may be the space taken by the button is conflicting with the upfront screen

Comment: i run it on windows not in my phone

Comment: i think flutter still have a lot of unrelated exceptions that till now didn't fixed.

Comment: i feel the error logs are because of the spacer you have used in the button just comment it down and try again

Answer (score 0):

- `Expanded widget` inside the `TextField` is not correct. The `Expanded widget` should be placed directly inside a `Flex widget`, but in your code, it is placed inside an `OverflowBar widget`.
- Remove `Expanded widget` and wrap the `TextField` with a `Flexible widget` instead.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: TextField(
        expands: true,
        maxLines: null,
        onChanged: (newDes) {
          setState(() {
            body = newDes;
          });
        },
        controller: desCTL,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'description',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Wrap(
      children: [
        for (final label in widget.note.labels)
          Chip(label: Text(label.name ?? ''))
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

- By using the `Flexible widget`, the `TextField` will take up the available space and expand vertically based on its content

`Edit`: To have UI with a `multiline TextField` and `persistent footer buttons`, you can wrap the Column containing the TextField and the Wrap widget inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. This will enable scrolling when the content exceeds the available space.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    shadowColor: null,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      onPressed: () {
        addNote();
        GoRouter.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          child: TextField(
            expands: true,
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: (newDes) {
              setState(() {
                body = newDes;
              });
            },
            controller: desCTL,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'description',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: [
            for (final label in widget.note.labels)
              Chip(label: Text(label.name ?? ''))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  persistentFooterButtons: [
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.library_add_outlined),
      onPressed: () {
        final note = addNote();
        context.push('/${AppRoutes.addLabelsToNote}', extra: note);
      },
    ),
    const Spacer(),
    Text(timeago.format(widget.note.updatedTime)),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer but the exception was the using of persistentFooterButtons that i used. but how i can achieve the UI that i want since the persistentFooterButtons made exceptions.

Comment: But the textfield got all of space not just based on its content and other things is the scrolling problem

Comment: did u try that in your idea and run that because i did the same thing but i got alot of errors

Comment: and also the textfield get all of space not based on its content thanks.